# Python can a dictionary value be a sum of its other values

Tags: python, dictionary

I am making a dictionary and wanted it to be able to keep track of some distances and add them,

e.g. `"R2_y": rd["2001"]["foo6"]["R1_y"] + rd["2001"]["foo6"]`

I am beginning to think it is impossible in a single dictionary.
*Code1* works only so long as the first "dicty" is present, otherwise the console returns that dicts is not defined, which is the same issue I have with "code2".

Is there a way to do this via other methods

**Code 1**

```
dicty = {"a": 11, "b": 2,"c": "a"+"b"}



dicty = {"a": 11, "b": 2,"c": dicty["a"] + dicty["b"]}
for k, v in dicty.items():
    print(k, " : ", v)
```

**Code2**

```
rd = {"1002": {"foo6": {"R1_y": "blank", "gap1": "blank"},
               "foo12": {"R1_y": "blank", "gap1": "blank"},
               "foo40": {"R1_y": "blank", "gap1": "blank"}}, 
      "1003": {"foo6": {"R1_y": "blank", "gap1": "blank"},
               "foo12": {"R1_y": "blank", "gap1": "blank"},
               "foo40": {"R1_y": "blank", "gap1": "blank"}},
      "2001": {"foo6": {"R1_y": 1000.0, 
                        "gap1": 100, 
                        "gap2": 11, 
                        "R2_y": rd["2001"]["foo6"]["R1_y"] + rd["2001"]["foo6"]["gap1"]},
                "foo12": {},
                "foo40": {}},
                 }

for k, v in rd.items():
    print(k, " : ", v)
```

**Traceback**

File "/Users/path/delete_me_7.py", line 20, in 
"R2_y": rd["2001"]["foo6"]["R1_y"] + rd["2001"]["foo6"]["gap1"]},
NameError: name 'rd' is not defined

Comment: Do you need the value to be defined once and for all as the sum of two other values, or does it need to change when one of those values change too?

Comment: the other values won't be changing during runtime, the R2_y value just needs to be a sum of them.

Comment: You can't do something like `dicty = {"a": 11, "b": 2,"c": dicty["a"] + dicty["b"]}`, because you first evaluate the rhs and then store that result to `dicty`. But during the evaluation of the rhs, `dicty` doesn't exist yet (or may be assigned to a different object).

Comment: You can do `dicty = {**(d := {"a": 11, "b": 2}), "c": d["a"] + d["b"]}` but why would you do it that way?

Comment: But you can create the base values in one step then add more key-value pairs for the additions next.

Comment: Im wondering if im better off using a json file to store the data and then have a dict add them where necessary?